# What's causing this issue with 2/3 module compatibility in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have a directory structure like this:

```
> coolmod
-> __init__.py
-> coolmod.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have:

```
from coolmod import *
```

I also have a directory of unittests, which run fine in both python 2 and 3. However, when I go above to the directory containing `coolmod` the `__init__.py` command is only run in Python 2. In Python 3, I get `AttributeError: module 'coolmod' has no attribute 'coolfunc'`. What changed and what do I have to do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: The 2/3 difference may be because implicit imports are possible on Python 2, but removed in Python 3.  How exactly are you running your tests and with what test runner?

Comment: I'm running `python -m unittest discover`. It has the same issue with python3 when I try to run it outside of the main directory though, just noticed that.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean about implicit imports being removed in python3?

Comment: It doesn't seem like implicit imports is your issue.